# Json schema not validating as expected

Tags: json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

**I am working on a Json schema for validation but it does not seem to be working.**
*Apart from the if then condition, the rest works fine but even though i am following the example provided in jsonschema - Applying Subschemas Conditionally, it does not work.*
*This is the schema*

'''

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "definitions": {
    "identifierKey": {
      "type": "string",
      "pattern": "^[a-z][a-z0-9]*(_[a-z0-9]+)*$",
      "minLength": 2
    },
    "uuid": {
      "type": "string",
      "pattern": "^[0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{12}$",
      "minLength": 36,
      "maxLength": 36
    },
    "mail_identifierKey": {
      "pattern": "^(?:(?!.*?[.]{2})[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9.+!%-]{1,64}|)|\"[a-zA-Z0-9.+!% -]{1,64}\")@[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9.-]+(.[a-z]{2,}|.[0-9]{1,})$"
    },
    "question_type": {
      "enum": [
        "barcode",
        "name",
        "nps",
        "single_choice",
        "text",
        "date",
        "number",
        "id",
        "mail_address",
        "multiple_choice",
        "phone_number",
        "zip_code",
        "rating"
      ]
    },
    "question": {
      "type": "object",
      "additionalProperties": false,
      "properties": {
        "key": {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/identifierKey"
        },
        "type": {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/question_type"
        }
      },
      "required": ["key", "type"]
    },
    "answers": {
      "type":"array",
      "items": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "question": {
            "$ref": "#/definitions/question"
          },
          "status": {
            "type": "string"
          }
        },
        "allOf": [
          {"if": {
            "properties": { "question": { "const": "rating" } } },
          "then": {
            "properties": { "value": { "type": "number", "minimum": 1, "maximum": 5 } } }
          },
          {"if": {
            "properties": { "question": { "const": "zip_code" } } },
           "then": {
            "properties": { "value": { "type": "string", "$ref": "#/definitions/identifierKey","minLength": 4, "maxLength": 10 } } }
          },
          {"if": {
            "properties": { "question": { "const": "phone_number" } } },
          "then": {
            "properties": { "value": { "type": "string", "minLength": 8, "maxLength": 15 } } }
          },
          {"if": {
            "properties": { "question": { "const": "multiple_choice" } } },
           "then": { 
            "properties": { "value": { "type": "array", "minItems": 1, "uniqueItems": true,
                "contains": { "type": "string" } } 
              } 
            } 
          },
          {"if": {
            "properties": { "question": { "const": "single_choice" } } },
           "then": {
            "properties": { "value": {"type": "string","$ref": "#/definitions/identifierKey"} } }
          },
          {"if": {
            "properties": { "question": { "const": "mail_address" } } },
           "then": {
            "properties": { "value": {"type": "string","$ref": "#/definitions/mail_identifierKey"} } }
          },
          {"if": {
            "properties": { "question": { "const": "id" } } },
           "then": {
            "properties": { "value": {"type": "string","$ref": "#/definitions/uuid"} } }
          },
          {"if": {
            "properties": { "question": { "const": "number" } } },
           "then": {
            "properties": { "value": {"type": "number"} } }
          },
          {"if": {
            "properties": { "question": { "const": "text" } } },
           "then": {
            "properties": { "value": {"type": "string"} } }
          },
          {"if": {
            "properties": { "question": { "const": "date" } } },
           "then": {
            "properties": { "value": {"type": "string", "format": "date"} } }
          },
          {"if": {
            "properties": { "question": { "const": "nps" } } },
           "then": {
            "properties": { "value": {"type": "number", "minimum": 1, "maximum":10 } } }
          },
          {"if": {
            "properties": { "question": { "const": "name" } } },
           "then": {
            "properties": { "value": {"type": "string" } } }
          },
          {"if": {
            "properties": { "question": { "const": "barcode" } } },
           "then": {
            "properties": { "value": {"type": "number" } } }
          }
        ]  
      }
    }
  },
  "properties": {
    "answers": {
      "$ref": "#/definitions/answers"
    }
  }
}
```

'''

**and this is what i am trying to validate**

```
''' {
    "$schema": "./blank.json",
    "answers":[ {
        "status": "hello1",
        "question": {
            "key": "hello",
            "type": "rating"
        },
        "value": 1234
    }]
} '''
```

i am following the example below but not able to figure out what i am missing

- https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/conditionals.html

Comment: https://json-everything.net/json-schema says the instance (the data) is valid against the schema.  (There's a trailing comma on line 128 of the schema.)  Where have you tried it?  Is that validator outputing any errors?

Comment: I also see that an empty object passes validation.  Can you edit the question with what you're expecting?

Comment: i am using vscode. When i am using the schema without if then condition, it validated the json correctly. But with the if then condition in "allof" nothing happens.

Comment: @gregsdennis i am trying to achive that the value is based on the question type given.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay... I see the problem.

Here's the `if` subschema that you expect to trigger for your data

```json
{
  "properties": {
    "question": { "const": "rating" }
  }
}
```

However, in your data, `question` has a `type` property.

```json
"question": {
  "key": "hello",
  "type": "rating"
}
```

This means that the `if` subschema isn't passing because `{"key": "hello", "type": "rating" }` != `"rating"`.

You'll need to update your `if` subschema to account for this property hierarchy.

```json
{
  "properties": {
    "question": {
      "properties": {
        "type": { "const": "rating" }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You'll need to do this for all of the `if` subschemas.

Making just this change gives this error on my validator:

```json
{
  "valid": false,
  "keywordLocation": "#/properties/answers/$ref/items/allOf/0/then/properties/value/maximum",
  "absoluteKeywordLocation": "https://json-everything/base#/definitions/question_type/items/allOf/0/then/properties/value/maximum",
  "instanceLocation": "#/answers/0/value",
  "error": "1234 is greater than or equal to 5"
}
```